Discussing shirk in a case study is haram? Have I committed shirk?
We were in a workshop where there was a case study in which we were acting as leaders of tribe and discussing how our tribe should be allowed to go to a stone and perform religious ceremony and worship. As a leader of the tribe, I had to negotiate for my tribe to be allowed to go and do worship. A lot of discussion included me saying "allow us this time to go there and let us pray"
Did I perform shirk? There was no intention. It was just for the case study and only a role play. We did not do shirk. Only for the case study we had to fight a case of letting or people go and worship stones.
Please help as I'm worried

salam!
Discussing shirk in a case study is not at all haram.
If your intention was to discuss shirk to clarify misconceptions or to promote
the correct understanding of Islamic principles, and you avoided any form of shirk
in your discussion, then you have not committed shirk.
Shirk may be  as those who make du’a or pray to someone other than Allah,
or seek his help or seek refuge with him with regard to matters
over which no one has control except Allah
Shirk may sometimes take the form of actions Such as one who sacrifices,
prays or prostrates to something other than Allah, or who promulgates laws to
replace the rulings of Allah and makes that the law to which people are
obliged to refer for judgement; or one who supports the kafirs and helps
them against the believers.
Other acts that go against the basic meaning of faith of Islam.
The primary intent should be to educate, clarify misconceptions,
and promote a deeper understanding of Islamic principles.
If you still think that you have done anything wrong you can repent and
ask Allah for forgiveness.
